# How to share variables between two middlewares node.js and apollo server?

Tags: node.js, middleware, apollo-server

I am using apollo server and graphql on my backend side.

I have two middlewares, one for authorization and another for counting users mutation queries.

In autohorization middleware I am authorizing current user and fetching all his data.
In count middleware I am checking type of query and increasing counter, for this I need user's id which is fetched in authorize middleware.

Is there any elegant and easy solution how to transfer this id from one middleware to another (from authroization to counter)?

This is call of both middlewares:

```
const apolloServerConfig = {
    schema,
    dataSources,
    context: async ({ req }) => ({ user: await autorizationMiddleware(req), counter: await counterMiddleware(req) }),
}
```

First middleware:

```
const { AuthenticationError } = require('apollo-server')
const AuthService = require('../auth')


module.exports = async (req) => {

    const { authorization } = req.headers



    if (!authorization) throw new AuthenticationError('not authorized')

    else {
    /......./
    
    
    return { id, email, name, lastname }
}
```

Conter middleware:

```
module.exports = async (req) => {

    //...get id of user for further actions

        
}
```

Comment: Are you referring to [graphql-middleware](https://github.com/prisma-labs/graphql-middleware) or something else? Please elaborate since Apollo Server does not itself support "middleware".

Comment: I edited question, yes it it graphql middleware

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not [graphql-middleware](https://github.com/prisma-labs/graphql-middleware) :) These are just functions you're calling each time your context is created. If you want to pass information between them, just call and await the first function, then call the second function with the `id` as a parameter and then finally return your context object.

```
context: async ({ req }) => {
  const user = await authorizationMiddleware(req);
  const counter = await counterMiddleware(req, user.id)
  return { user, counter }
}
```

Comment: Would you please be kind and show it how it would look like on code, I am not sure I understand you. Thank you :D